# How to save images from Python Interactive tab in Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I am using the Python Interactive tab (similar to Jupyter notebooks) in Microsoft Visual Studio Code.

When I plot an image, I am unable to save it directly from the editor. There's no option to save it directly with the mouse, or to save it directly from the interface.

Is there a way to save it from the interface or should I only use `matplotlib`'s savefig method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully sure if this counts as a full answer here on Stack Overflow. But the answer here is that we don't have a way to do this currently. You can highlight it in the interactive window and Ctrl-C to copy it out, but even that support is rather flakey at this point. If you would like to log this issue this would be the best spot to get it on our radar:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues
We keep our issues open to the public so you can track when we work on it after it's filed there.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed now there was already an issue I wasn't able to find earlier: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4132

Comment: Yeah, that issue would cover it. I added on a link to this thread and mentioned the possibility of a save button for graphs as well in addition to CTRL-C and the context menu idea.

Comment: @Ian Huff, on the same page, is there a way to change the resolution of the plots being saved as PNG, like there is in spyder?

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: @MaximeBeau no we don't currently have that option. If you would like, you could file a suggestion for that on our github repo here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues. Items on there, in particular ones that get more upvotes often get put into our upcoming work.

Comment: Any news on this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

In my version (1.47.3) I can double click the image, which opens it in  a separate tab for inspection.

One of the buttons in this tab is a save icon, which allows you to save the image in a format that depends on the file ending you choose. I've tried .png, but couldn't find an option to change resolution. .pdf or .svg saves it losslessly as vector graphic.

In the image below you can see what it looks like for me. (on Ubuntu)
[image: screenshot of multiple tabs]